# Copy and paste formula in excel

Tags: excel, copy, formula

Good morning everyone,
I have sheet1 where I past information from SAP. 
In a second tab and for each line in sheet1 I have to copy paste the info on 6 lines

What I did is 
cell A1 of sheet 2 is "=sheet1!A1"
cell A2 to A6 "=A1", ="A2" etc..

Problem is, I have about 500 lines in sheet one, and when I try to copy past the formula, in the cell A7, the "=sheet!A1" becomes  "=sheet!A6" where I need it to be "=sheet!A2"

Could someone help me please ?

Thanks a lot for the support

Pierre

Answer (score 1):

Write following formula in `Sheet2` cell `A1`:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,CEILING(ROWS($A$1:A1)/6,1))`

Copy down as much as you need.

Edit:
Tweaked formula per OP's latest info which should go into cell `F5` or whatever cell:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,CEILING(ROWS($A$1:A1)/6,1)+2)`

Notice

> +2

which is added so as to start directly from Row 3 instead of Row 1!

Comment: Hi.. thanks a lot for this ;) how can i do if data to pickup is from SHEET1 but cell B3 ? i tried to solve myself but always have result from sheet1 cell B1 instead of B3

Comment: Do you mean you want to start from `Sheet1!B3` and then go onto B4,B5 etc after every 6 rows?

Comment: In fact my data on Sheet1 start on cell B3 and in sheet2 I will past your formula in the cell F5 ==> when i do this, I will have in Sheet2 cell F5/F6 the correct data, but only twice, then the "6" results start as of cell F7

Comment: @CarHibou See edit. You could've included this information in your post.

Comment: you are right but I did not want to make it to "complicated" and thought that I could have find the solution by myself. unfortunately, i could not. thanks a lot for your help